# System design for an extendable approval workflow for different type of entities

Tags: c#, workflow, system-design

I'm looking for an efficient way to create drafts and start an approval workflow for some of the entities in my domain. Users should easily track changes and approve or reject the changes. Would you please suggest a generic model / approach / roadmap to easily provide these functionalities?

Let's say I have this model:

```
public class CourierDistributionArea
{
    public City City { get; set; }
    public Courier Courier { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Courier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And let's say the user adds or updates or deletes a few CourierDistributionArea entities. How would you store the new pending approval version of these entities? And how would you design this system to easily add new type of entities to be used in this approval workflow? How would you present the changeset to the end user?

Comment: Why are you voting to close the question? If stackoverflow is not a right place for these kind of questions, what platform do you suggest?

Comment: Your question is too broad. It has more than one topic/problem space, and it's also too abstract instead of directly having programming concern.

Comment: I would create a developer Salesforce account and use their built-in workflow approval process :p -- seriously though if this is an assignment and not a work related task and you have the freedom to use whatever you'd like then this is probably the easiest option (mostly point and click -- if you know Salesforce administration then way easier, if you know Apex that will help some depending on any customization you would like to do). There are ways to integrate Salesforce with your application as well. Unless you know how to use these already though probably not the easiest way.

Comment: Should new drafts be based on the most recent draft, or only on approved changes?

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn new drafts should be based only on approved changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of options and these will depend on the likely changes made by your users, whether multiple users can provide alternative drafts simultaneously, and what storage you want to use (I'm ignorantly assuming some table-based RDBMS like SQL Server).

## 1. Draft Table(s)

Create a `CarDraft` table alongside your `Car` table. All columns in the target table should be present in the draft table, alongside any additional columns you require for metadata relating to the draft itself. When the draft is approved, upsert the relevant columns into the target table and delete the draft.

**Pros**

- No need to support multiple versions of the same entity in the same table
- Drafts don't affect OLTP on the target table in any way

**Cons**

- Additional table to maintain

## 2. Versioned Entities

Create `Version` and `Published` columns on your target table and relax the constraints on enforcing a single row with the original primary key, instead allowing multiple rows, but only one with a `Published` column set to true.

**Pros**

- No additional table to maintain
- No need to write row twice (just delete old row and flip `Published` bit on new one in a single transaction)

**Cons**

- Potentially more complicated constraints / application validation
- Additional checks when joining against `Published` column (easy to forget)

## 3. Transformation Approval

Again, depending on the operations users can perform to modify entities, you could store the change operation itself rather than the new state as a draft. This could be stored in an `CarModifications` table for example, potentially as a partial JSON object, or as a number or rows, each one representing a change of value to a column on the target table. Multiple rows could be grouped as a single OperationId if required.

**Pros**

- No changes to target table
- Multiple changes across multiple tables could be keyed on a single operation id and applied in a transaction

**Cons**

- More complicated modelling
- More complicated validation